# Wordpress plugin shortcodes not outputting anything

Tags: shortcode, api

I'm in the process of creating a WordPress plugin that retrieves information from a Minecraft Server. I have the script to do this working fine as just a PHP script, however, when I try to convert that Script to a Plugin, it won't work.

I orignally used cURL functions, but after some googling I learned that that is not allowed within WP, so I changed the cURL functions to `wp_remote_get`.

The problem is, the shortcodes that I have created will not output anything. I really can't figure out what the problem is, so I decided to post here after a couple days of googling.

Here are the plugin contents:
https://gist.github.com/th3no0b/1fa9aba11789160d9e48

(the file directories are right as far as I can see, `mcq-core.php`, `mcq-functions.php` and `mcq-shortcodes.php` files are in the `core` folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_remote_get` doesn't return a string, it returns an array, and if we refer to the documentation:

```
$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://www.example.com/index.html' );
if( is_array($response) ) {
  $header = $response['headers']; // array of http header lines
  $body = $response['body']; // use the content
}
```

Here $response would not be a json string, but an array containing the headers and a body, the body containing a json string.

So:

```
function mcq_getMcApi($type){
    // This function mcq_gets the information from "mcapi.ca" if required
    $json = wp_remote_get("https://mcapi.ca/query/$ip/$type");
    return json_decode($json,true);
}
```

becomes:

```
function mcq_getMcApi($type){
    // This function mcq_gets the information from "mcapi.ca" if required
    $response = wp_remote_get("https://mcapi.ca/query/$ip/$type");
    return json_decode($response['body'],true);
}
```

Note that `wp_remote_get` will return a `WP_Error` object that you should check for it any of this fails, and you should check the response, as it may not be a json string.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the `mcq_getMcApi()` function, however there is still no output.

Comment: I checked if what was being returned was just text, which it wasn't, so I've adjusted that. My function is now like so https://gist.github.com/th3no0b/3b411cf053b5c8211120 however it still doesn't output anything... :/

Comment: Then further debugging is going to be needed, your code contains a large number of assumptions, but never checks these assumptions are true ( e.g. assuming your remote request worked or that it returns a string not an array, it still doesn't check for a WP_Error object )

Comment: Of note, you use `$online` in every function, but inside each function that variable is out of scope and thus undefined

Comment: The same is true of all the other variables, they all resolve to `''` so your shortcodes output nothing. You should read up on global variables and variable scope, or make use of objects and member variables to store state internally

Comment: Ah-ha! I assumed that functions could use variables that were defined before it. Thanks a lot! The shortcodes now output stuff! Now to figure out why $online is returning `false`...

Comment: Figured it out. I was using the wrong variable in `json_decode` within `mcq_getMcApi()` function. All working now! Thanks for the help.